# C# .net 4.0 tabControl1_DrawItem event firing constantly

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

I added a feature to one of my programs recently and noticed something very odd. The feature required me to add a new tab to the tab control I am using. This then pushed the tabs past what could be displayed on the form with default sizes requiring the arrows to navigate the tabs on the tab control.

[image]

The problem I discovered is that if these arrows on the tab control exist, the tabControl1_DrawItem event was firing every few milliseconds causing the program to become sluggish and use about 15% to 20% CPU when just sitting there doing nothing after the form load event.

Once I increased the form size so the arrows didn't exist, the event only fired when the form was moved or a different tab was selected.

I searched all day for this and debugged and found the answer or I guess you can say workaround, but not here. So I guess I have two questions. Why does the event fire constantly if the arrows exist, and is there anything possible to prevent it from doing this since I am not able to prevent users of the application from resizing the form and make this happen?

This is the code I have under the event.

```
private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
Platform.Log(LogLevel.Debug, "DrawItem event is being called.");
//Draw the tabs on the tab conrol
e.DrawBackground();
using (Brush br = new SolidBrush(TabColors[tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index]]))
{
    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(br, e.Bounds);
    SizeF sz = e.Graphics.MeasureString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font);
    e.Graphics.DrawString(tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index].Text, e.Font, DGVBrushForeColor, e.Bounds.Left + (e.Bounds.Width - sz.Width) / 2, e.Bounds.Top + (e.Bounds.Height - sz.Height) / 2 + 1);

    Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
    rect.Offset(0, 1);
    rect.Inflate(0, -1);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(DGVPenBackColor, rect);
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}

//To Fill the blank portion of the end of the tab control
SolidBrush fillbrush = new SolidBrush(BACK_COLOR);
//draw rectangle behind the tabs
Rectangle lasttabrect = tabControl1.GetTabRect(tabControl1.TabPages.Count - 1);
Rectangle background = new Rectangle();
background.Location = new Point(lasttabrect.Right, 0);

//pad the rectangle to cover the 1 pixel line between the top of the tabpage and the start of the tabs
background.Size = new Size(tabControl1.Right - background.Left, lasttabrect.Height + 1);
e.Graphics.FillRectangle(fillbrush, background);
}
```

Comment: The event does not fire constantly if the arrows exist, so show your code that duplicates the problem.

Comment: @LarsTech Testing shows that in my case if the arrows exist it happens, if they don't exist, it only happens when it should.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't duplicate the problem though.  The issue is coming from somewhere else.

Comment: @LarsTech In debugging this event gets fired during the Form Load event, and I paint the tabcontrol and load the form. If the arrows exist it is called repeatedly. This is a large program but honestly that is all that's to it for the program to start up. What more can I provide?

Comment: The Draw event does not fire in the load event — the form isn't visible yet.  You have to find out why your draw event is firing prematurely.

Comment: DrawItem is like OnPaint method. If that control need to be painted, the method will be called. How about put all your object creation outside DrawItem method, like "SolidBrush fillbrush = new SolidBrush(BACK_COLOR);" and "Rectangle background = new Rectangle();". You can create it once, and use it there, but not create it all the time.

Comment: Ok Guys I did find something weird. I have two events tabControl1_DrawItem and tabControl1_DrawItem_1 that are both firing on startup. I hit break points in each routine. I will have to look into this and debug it. Right now I am leaving to go to SummerFest! So tomorrow.

Comment: Ok What happened is the tabControl1_DrawItem_1 was set at design time, and I manually added the tabControl1_DrawItem in the form load event. I have put all code used in the tabControl1_DrawItem event and updated the question. I still do not understand why the event fires constantly if the tab control arrows are present.

Comment: Don't use the WS_EX_COMPOSITED hack.

Comment: @Hans You are correct that is what is causing it. The problem is if I do not use that the tabs flicker constantly, so I believe I will use set the multiline property on the tab control to true to solve this one. I also found this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867978/ws-ex-composited-causes-entire-app-to-flicker-shimmer-when-tab-control-has-too-m

Answer (score 1):

The answer was found thanks to Hans Passant's help. I implemented this code found here on stackoverflow in my application.

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int style = NativeWinAPI.GetWindowLong(this.Handle, NativeWinAPI.GWL_EXSTYLE);
        style |= NativeWinAPI.WS_EX_COMPOSITED;
        NativeWinAPI.SetWindowLong(this.Handle, NativeWinAPI.GWL_EXSTYLE, style);
    }

    internal static class NativeWinAPI
    {
        internal static readonly int GWL_EXSTYLE = -20;
        internal static readonly int WS_EX_COMPOSITED = 0x02000000;

        [DllImport("user32")]
        internal static extern int GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex);

        [DllImport("user32")]
        internal static extern int SetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, int nIndex, int dwNewLong);
    }
```

This is what caused the problem with the draw event firing constantly when the tab navigation arrows where present. To solve the problem I set the Multiline property of the tab control to true. This prevents the navigation arrows from showing up and it is acceptable to have multiple rows of tabs for me.

I also want to note that without this code the problem does not happen, but the tabs flicker constantly and crazy without the "WS_EX_COMPOSITED hack" as Hans called it. With double buffering everything using this hack,  it makes everything work well so it is staying in there for now in this application.