# Flicker when moving/resizing window

Tags: windows, image, winapi, flicker

I have developed an application to display jpeg images. It can display 4 images, one in each quadrant of the screen. It uses 4 windows for that. The windows have no border (frame) nor titlebar.
When a new image is loaded, the window size is adjusted for the new image and then the image is displayed.

Especially when the window is made larger, there is often a flicker. With my eyes to slits, it seems that the old contents is moved when resizing before the new contents is displayed.

I consulted many resources and used all tricks:

- the window has only style `CS_DBLCLKS` (no `CS_HREDRAW` or `CS_VREDRAW`);
- the background brush is NULL;
- `WM_ERASEBKGND` returns 1;
- `WM_NCPAINT` returns 0;
- `WM_NCCALCSIZE` tells to align to the side not moved (can you tell it to discard the client area?);
- `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` returns 0;
- SetWindowPos has flags `SWP_NOCOPYBITS | SWP_DEFERERASE | SWP_NOREDRAW | SWP_NOSENDCHANGING`.

Still, the flicker (or the contents move) occurrs when resizing the window. What I want is to:

- SetWindowPos to new size and position;
- InvalidateRect (hWnd, NULL, FALSE);
- UpdateWindow(hWnd);

without any painting, background erasing or content moving until `WM_PAINT`.

`WM_PAINT` does:

```
hDC= BeginPaint (hWnd, &ps);
hMemDC= CreateCompatibleDC (hDC);
hOldBitmap = SelectObject (hMemDC, hNewBitmap);
BitBlt (hDC,...,hMemDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);
SelectObject (hMemDC, hOldBitmap);
DeleteDC (hMemDC);
EndPaint (hWnd, &ps);
```

Can anyone tell me if/where I make a mistake that causes the old content of the window to be moved?

Hardware etc: Windows 7 on HP Elitebook Core7 64 bits with NVIDIA Quadro K1000m driver 9.18.13.3265 (updated to 341.44).

---

**UPDATE** (Jul '17)

I have seen the behavior of the pogram also on another Windows computer (Windows 8/10). It does not seem to be the NVIDIA display driver.

The behavior is the most visible when resizing a window tiled to the centre of the screen (right bottom = w/2, h/2) to the left or left upper corner (0, 0).

I may have problems with the calculations for the WM_NCCALCSIZE message to tell Windows not to do anything. Could anyone give an example calculation for my purpose? See also [How do I force windows NOT to redraw anything in my dialog when the user is resizing my dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165759/how-do-i-force-windows-not-to-redraw-anything-in-my-dialog-when-the-user-is-resiz)

Comment: add `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` to main window. If nothing helps you use glew - glsl

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин, `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` did not make a difference. Note that all windows are top-level windows with style `WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW` and class style `CS_DBLCLKS`, so I assume each one is a "main window" as you mention.

Answer (score 1):

You have an impressive list of anti-flickering tricks :-)

I don't know if this is of importance (since it depends on how your tool windows are created and espacially if they are child windows to a common parent):
Try setting window style `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` in the parent window of the tool windows (if there is one).

If not set the parent window will erase it's (entire) background and then forward the paint messages to the child windows which will cause flickering. If `WS_CLIPCHILDREN` is set the parent window does nothing to the client area occupied by child windows. As a result the area of child windows isn't drawn twice and there is no chance for flickering.

Comment: Hi Lukas, All windows are free-standing, non-overlapping on the desktop (which I set to a black .bmp file with desktop icons hidden) and there are no other windows on the desktop. The parent window is moved off the screen when the viewers are busy. Hence I thought no need to clip as there is nothing to clip.  
Windows are created with WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, and then later set to:  
ww &= ~(WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_CAPTION|WS_MAXIMIZEBOX|WS_MINIMIZEBOX|WS_SIZEBOX|WS_SYSMENU)  
ww |=  (WS_POPUP);

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Hi Paul, I already thought that your windows are free-standing ... but it was worth a shot. Interresting that it flickers even with a black background. I've never seen such a behavior.

Comment: I am beginning to suspect it is more a problem with the NVIDIA and its driver than it is a problem of my programing. Especially as I see through the slits of my eyes that the window's contents is moved before the WM_PAINT occurs.  The behavior is also sporadic (not always), which could point to interference with the refresh rate. I have little reference to other current machines but have never seen the behavior on any of my older machines.

Answer (score 1):

This is a theory more than an answer:

By default, in modern Windows, your window is just a texture on the video card, and the desktop window manager is mapping that to a rectangle on the screen.  You've seem to have done everything necessary to make sure that texture gets updated in one fell swoop.

But when you resize the window, perhaps the desktop compositor immediately updates its geometry, causing the (still unchanged) texture to be appear in the new position on the screen.  It's only later, when you do the paint, that the texture is updated.

You can test this theory by temporarily turning off desktop compositing.  On Windows 7, you navigate to System Properties, choose the Advanced tab, under Performance choose Settings..., on the Visual Effects tab, deselect the "Enable desktop composition" setting.  Then try to reproduce the problem.  If it goes away, then that supports (but doesn't absolutely prove) my theory.

(Remember to re-enable compositing, since that's how most of your users will be running most of the time.)

If the theory is true, it seems the goal is to get to the paint as soon possible after the window resize.  If the window of time is small enough, then both could happen within a monitor refresh cycle and there would be no flicker.

Ironically, your efforts to eliminate flicker may be working against you here, since you've intentionally suppressed the invalidation and redraw that would normally result from SetWindowPos until you do it manually at a later step.

A debugging tip:  Try introducing delays (e.g., `Sleep(1000);`) at key points in the process so you can see whether the resize and redraw are actually rendering on screen as two distinct steps.

Comment: Adrian, I will start testing. Thanks for your suggestion; I am quite desparate to eliminate the flicker.

Answer (score 1):

You have indeed got a nice set of tricks.

First I can suggest a few variants on the existing tricks that might help especially on XP/Vista/7, and second I want to mention where the persistent flicker you see on Win8/10 is likely coming from and some tricks to reduce that.

First, despite advice to the contrary in other OP posts, you may find that if you set the `CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW` window styles that you avoided before, it actually eliminates the `BitBlt` that is done inside the internal `SetWindowPos` Windows does during window resizing (but---and this is the confusing part---on Windows 8/10 you will still see flicker from another source...more on that below).

If you don't want to include `CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW`, you can also intercept `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` (first passing it onto `DefWindowProc`) and set `WINDOWPOS.flags |= SWP_NOCOPYBITS`, which disables the `BitBlt` inside the internal call to `SetWindowPos()` that Windows makes during window resizing.

Or, you could add to your `WM_NCCALCSIZE` trick by having it return a set of values that will tell Windows to just `BitBlt` 1 pixel on top of itself so that even if the `BitBlt` does happen, it doesn't do anything visibly:

```
case WM_NCCALCSIZE:
{
    RECT ocr; // old client rect
    if (wParam)
    {
        NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS *np = (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS *)lParam;
        // np->rgrc[0] is new window rect
        // np->rgrc[1] is old window rect
        // np->rgrc[2] is old client rect
        ocr = np->rgrc[2];
    }
    else
    {
        RECT *r = (RECT *)lParam;
        // *r is window rect
    }

    // first give Windoze a crack at it
    lRet = DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

    if (wParam)
    {
        NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS *np = (NCCALCSIZE_PARAMS *)lParam;

        // np->rgrc[0] is new client rect computed
        // np->rgrc[1] is going to be dst blit rect
        // np->rgrc[2] is going to be src blit rect
        // 
        ncr = np->rgrc[0];
        RECT &dst = np->rgrc[1];
        RECT &src = np->rgrc[2];

        // FYI DefWindowProc gives us new client rect that
        // - in y
        //   - shares bottom edge if user dragging top border
        //   - shares top edge if user dragging bottom border
        // - in x
        //   - shares left edge if user dragging right border
        //   - shares right edge if user dragging left border
        //
        src = ocr;
        dst = ncr; 

        // - so src and dst may have different size
        // - ms dox are totally unclear about what this means
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/
        //         winmsg/wm-nccalcsize
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/
        //         api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagnccalcsize_params
        // - they just say "src is clipped by dst"
        // - they don't say how src and dst align for blt
        // - resolve ambiguity

        // essentially disable BitBlt by making src/dst same
        // make it 1 px to avoid waste in case Windoze still does it

        dst.right  = dst.left + 1;
        dst.bottom = dst.top  + 1;

        src.right  = dst.left + 1;
        src.bottom = dst.top  + 1;

        lRet = WVR_VALIDRECTS;
    }
    else // wParam == 0: Windoze wants us to map a single rect w->c
    {
        RECT *r = (RECT *)lParam;
        // *r is client rect
    }

    return lRet;
```

So that's all very nice, but why does Windows 8/10 look so bad?

Apps under Windows 8/10 Aero don't draw directly to the screen, but rather draw to offscreen buffers that are then composited by the evil DWM.exe window manager.  DWM actually adds another layer of `BitBlt`-type behavior on top of the existing legacy XP/Vista/7 `BitBlt` behavior.

And the DWM blit behavior is even more crazy because they don't just copy the client area, but they actually replicate pixels at the edges of your old client area to make the new one.  Unfortunately, making DWM not do its blit is much harder than just passing some extra flags.

I don't have a 100% solution, but I hope the above info will help, and please see this Q&A for a timing trick you can use to reduce the chances of the DWM-layer blit happening to your app:

[How to smooth ugly jitter/flicker/jumping when resizing windows, especially dragging left/top border (Win 7-10; bg, bitblt and DWM)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000291/how-to-smooth-ugly-jitter-flicker-jumping-when-resizing-windows-especially-drag)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, Louis. I am currently testing the WS_EX_COMPOSITED flag that @АлексейНеудачин suggested in his comment. It seems to help a lot. I already do a WM_NCCALCSIZE but not yet of 1 bit, which eems a very good idea to fool Windows. That will be next.

Comment: `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` sounds interesting: if it is working it might mean that a BitBlt is still happening, but to an offscreen buffer whose contents are then updated by your draw routine before the buffer is displayed onscreen.   This suggests `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` is somehow not there on DWM though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4188486/1046167

Comment: Louis, your link suggests that the flag would do nothing. I will be testing soon with a vesion in which I can turn the flag on and off to study the result. I must say that since some time it _seems_ the flicker is less, suggesting a possible [undocumented] bug fix by MS for my Windows 7. Following testing the flag, I will test a calcsize of 1 pixel.

Comment: Louis, I tried all your suggestions, but they didn't work. I included `CS_HREDRAW|CS_VREDRAW` with and without intercepting `WM_NCCALCSIZE` with a one pixel rects. Neither does `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` give any improvement. In my setup I see no `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` message.

Comment: My order is: Icall `SetWindowPos`, then follows a `WM_NCCALCSIZE` and `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED`, I then call `InvalidateRect` and `UpdateWindow` and then follows a `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: Bummer.  By the way, is there any particular reason why you create four borderless toplevel windows? Maybe if you just made one larger toplevel window and then drew your content onto that window you could get the same on-screen look (pixel for pixel) and then maybe one of the jitter workarounds would work?

Comment: That would mean a major rework, though doable; however, I wouldn't be able to see what is behind the windows, which I sometimes want.

Answer (score 0):

Just in addition to your list of tricks. I have the same problem with flicker on my Dell XPS notebook while resizing window using left/top edge. I've tried all the tricks you mentioned. As far as I understand window border is drawn in GPU and the window content is prepared in GDI subsystem and transferred to video memory for window composition (DWM introduced in Windows 8.1). I tried to remove GDI rendering completely (setting WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP style) which makes window without any content, and then create content surface directly using DXGI subsystem (using CreateSwapChainForComposition, there are few examples on how to do this). But the problem remains. There is still a lag between rendering a window frame and resizing/displaying content surface.

However it may solve your problem, as you don't have the border and you will not notice this lag. But you will have full control over window repaint and it will be made on GPU side.