# How can I achieve sprite composition that actually works?

Tags: c#, winforms

My requirements:

- A control with a background can have sprites drawn on it.
- It needs to be possible to move sprites around programmatically and by setting up dragging events.
- The sprite's image may have alpha transparency; sprites must correctly alpha-blend with both the background and each other.
- Drawing order must match the logical order of sprites - clicking on a sprite that appears to be on top should initiate dragging that sprite, never one that appears underneath it.

## Attempt 1

The obvious approach is to create a custom control to represent the Sprite. Let's try it:

```
public partial class Sprite : Control
{
    public Sprite()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
```

For testing purposes, we'll make it so clicking a Sprite just brings it to the front, no dragging yet:

```
        this.Click += Sprite_Click;
    }

    void Sprite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.BringToFront();
    }
```

So we can identify each sprite and verify the drawing order, let's set a 'frame' color for each:

```
    public Color FrameColor { get; set; }
```

And draw the sprites as a translucent white body with a solid-colour frame - we should then be able to verify that the background appears shaded behind a single space, shaded more strongly where sprites overlap, and the borders overlap as expected:

```
    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        Graphics g = pe.Graphics;
        g.FillRectangle(
            new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(128, 255, 255, 255)),
            DisplayRectangle
        );
        g.DrawRectangle(new Pen(FrameColor, 10), DisplayRectangle);
    }
```

And then we can design a form with a dark background, set up a few Sprites on it, make them overlap, give them different frame colours, and test.

**Naturally, it doesn't work.** Controls by default have a background colour, which appears to default to white, or something close to it. So these sprites overlap properly, but they have opaque white middles.

## Attempt 2

Well, surely we can just set that background colour to transparent? A bit of Googling in Microsoft's documentation tells us that we certainly can, but not directly ([as someone else on SO found out the hard way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586322/why-am-i-getting-control-does-not-support-transparent-background-colors)). It needs a bit of configuration:

```
        // in constructor
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Okay, so now the background shows through each Sprite, but **the Sprite borders don't show through each other**. What gives? A little more Googling tells us that this 'transparent background colour' support is actually a bit of a hack; basically, the parent Control implements its background painting to copy image data from the parent component and composite with that, ignoring everything else.

To be totally honest, I expected the system to be designed such that this would just work automatically - i.e., *any* time *any* drawing occurs, it composites with whatever's underneath it on screen, and the only reason controls aren't constantly showing through each other is because of their explicitly opaque backgrounds. But no such luck. I guess the whole system was designed back when people didn't want that sort of thing by default, for performance reasons.

Anyway.

## Attempt 3

Well, if the background painting is what's causing the problem, maybe we can just disable it completely?

```
    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs ignored) { }
```

**Nope**. If we click on sprites, we can see them re-order, and composite with each other - but they *don't composite with the background image*. And, more strangely, when the parent window is invalidated (by resizing the form, or minimizing and restoring it), the sprites turn opaque again.

## Attempt 4

After even more Googling, we find StackOverflow answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9359642) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15523544), articles like [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20121226091810/http://www.bobpowell.net/transcontrols.htm) etc. And they all point at the same low-level hack:

```
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | 0x20; 
            return cp;
        }
    }
```

For this to work, we *also* need to disable painting the background, but of course it no longer matters if we set up that "transparent" background, since that painting logic has been suppressed. (Curiously, it's also possible to suppress painting the background by setting an `Opaque` option in the `ControlStyles`; while that sounds like the opposite of what we want, it seems to work about as well.)

Well. It **almost** works. The Sprites composite both with themselves and the background. But now a very curious thing happens: **the drawing order is wrong, and not even consistent**. Invalidating the window in different ways (resizing vs. minimizing and restoring) will bring a different Sprite to the front visually; but in general it doesn't correspond to what was clicked and in what order. If we add explicit invalidation logic:

```
    // in click event handler
    Parent.Invalidate(this.Bounds, true);
```

then clicking a sprite actually appears to *send it to the back* visually - although again, the drawing order may change if we resize the window or minimize and restore it.

---

What gives? How can I solve this once and for all? Options I've considered:

- Burn the controls to the ground; make a parent control keep track of a list of sprite `Images`, track mouse drag and click events, and do all the picking and rendering logic itself. Should be guaranteed to work, but is a ridiculous amount of work for the job.
- Make the controls not draw at all, by overriding both background and foreground painting, and have them expose a property with their desired Image. Let a parent handle all the rendering, but fall back on the built-in Control logic for picking, mouse drags etc. Less work, but seems iffy (maybe there's some hidden thing that still forces Controls to draw something?), is a fairly tightly coupled design, and might still have performance issues if a naive approach is taken to invalidation (?).

Comment: I've never managed to get this setup (control compositing over control) to work. In my experience (not necessarily best approach), just keeping all images and rendering to a bitmap (and finally rendering the bitmap to screen) is the easiest approach. Even with all the extra mouse logic, etc. it took me a couple of days to hook up roughly what you describe and performance was adequate.

Comment: winforms doesn't support transparency, or anything useful for that matter. Use proper XAML based technology such as WPF instead.

Comment: You could fix your `CreateParams` approach if you really wanted to; it's hard to say for sure without seeing your actual code, but probably you just haven't taken over control of when things get drawn, hence the inconsistent results. That said, a 1-to-1 sprite-to-control relationship just probably isn't what you want anyway; a Forms control is a whole window and is really too heavyweight for a good sprite-based system. You should, as xxbbcc suggests, manage the sprites yourself in a single control that hosts them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After even more research, I appear to have an answer.

---

First, some explanation about drawing order: as far as I can tell now, it *was* consistent in Attempt 4, but invalidating by resizing the window causes gradual invalidations of different areas, which produces misleading results. The order is always top to bottom, which is the opposite of what you want for compositing, but which enables optimizations when you treat everything as opaque by clipping the invalid regions. (I'm not sure how much CPU effort this really saves given that the clipping paths can potentially get quite complex, but I guess it also helps reduce flickering when you aren't using double-buffering, since you avoid repainting a given pixel on any given refresh.)

But as it happens, if you read between the lines, you [discover that](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/725b2288-2c6e-46b5-80b7-d13d4050bdec/may-i-manage-controls-drawing-order-by-myself?forum=vcgeneral) there is *another* flag in the "extended window styles" (the 0x20 flag that we set in Attempt 4 is `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT`), called [`WS_EX_COMPOSITED` (value 0x02000000)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff700543.aspx), that reverses the drawing order to be what we want instead. Or you could have just read the documentation more closely in the first place. Oops.

(You'd think they could have just designed it to take care of all this logic automatically - detect which sprites have a translucent or transparent background colour, draw the ones with opaque backgrounds top-down first for speed, then the others bottom-up for correctness while clipping around the opaque ones. Oh well.)

A quick note here: because compositing naturally involves repainting the same area multiple times, this flag also sets up double-buffering that applies across all children of the window created with that flag (as far as I can tell, in Windows API parlance, every control is a "window", as well as the forms themselves). So it seems that [people often use it to avoid flickering on forms with lots of controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25872849/to-reduce-flicker-by-double-buffer-setstyle-vs-overriding-createparam?rq=1), even when they don't intend for controls to overlap. However, ironically, `WS_EX_COMPOSITED` might actually **cause** [huge amounts of flickering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4188306/flicker-free-tab-control-with-ws-ex-composited) with certain controls, such as `TabPage`. (I'm running 8.1 and was able to reproduce the described problem very clearly.) The documentation states

> This cannot be used if the window has a class style of either CS_OWNDC or CS_CLASSDC.

So maybe that has something to do with it. We can avoid this by restricting the "composited area" to a region using a simple control such as a `Panel`. At least in my tests, that will fix the problem as long as the `TabPage` isn't a child of the `Panel`, even if it overlaps.

It also seems that this might not work under XP, but hey, it's 2014 now.

---

## Anyway, on to the code.

What we need to do is set a `CreateWindowEx` flag, with the same `CreateParams` technique, in some *ancestor* of the Sprite, such as the Form they're on:

```
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | 0x02000000;
        return cp;
    }
}
```

We *still need* the `WS_EX_TRANSPARENT` setting, and disabling of background paint on the Sprite controls, from attempts 3 and 4. We *don't* need to set up a transparent `BackColor`, because we're not going to paint the `BackColor`. I have no idea why allowing a *fully transparent* `BackColor` to be painted messes things up, but it apparently does.

This will apparently work even if there are intervening controls, i.e. if we put the `Sprite` controls inside a `Panel` on the `Form`. (If we want to restrict the effect to a `Panel`, as discussed above, we'd have to subclass Panel; but my project already does so :) ) Everything works perfectly in my test project, and I don't even need to explicitly `Invalidate` anything.

Comment: Interesting. when I tackled this problem, I just made each image a PictureBox the size of the whole canvas, inside the underlying image's PictureBox, and simply painted full-size images in them that had the actual image drawn on them at the right locations. That worked too.